# Bar plot colours do not match the cumulative sum of the names' frequency

Tags: r, ggplot2, cumsum

I am creating a stacked bar chart showing the most frequent words by a person. I have managed to stack up all the tokens using a cumulative sum, however, I have two problems:

1. the colour is not linked to the text in the bar chart for Don and
   I do not know why this happens since for Anna I get the right link between stocked up words and colour.
2. The first word in Anna's column is an emoji. This does show up in my data frame as an emoji but it does not in the ggplot. Any idea on how to make ggplot able to show emojis?

This is a subset of my dataset:

```
    structure(list(person = c("Don", "Anna", "Anna", "Anna", "Anna", 
    "Don", "Anna", "Don", "Don", "Don"), tokens = c("hey", "\U0001f44d\U0001f3fc", 
    "im", "yeh", "xx", "https", "guys", "yeah", "guys", "im"), n = c(13L, 
    14L, 17L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 22L, 27L, 32L), freq = c(0.00727476217123671, 
    0.0149413020277481, 0.0181430096051227, 0.0181430096051227, 0.0192102454642476, 
    0.0117515388919978, 0.0234791889007471, 0.0123111359820929, 0.0151091214325686, 
    0.0179071068830442), cumcount = c(13L, 14L, 31L, 48L, 66L, 34L, 
    88L, 56L, 83L, 115L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

this is the code:

```
plot2 %>% 
dplyr::filter(grepl("Anna|Don", person)) %>% 
group_by(person) %>%
arrange(n) %>% 
top_n(5,n) %>% 
mutate(cumcount=cumsum(n)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=person, y=n, fill=tokens, color=factor(tokens))) +
geom_col() +
geom_text(aes(y=cumcount, label=tokens), vjust=1.6, color="black", size=2.5)   
theme_minimal() +
theme(legend.position="none")
plot2
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need to do all the rpe-processing part with calculated the cumulative sum because `geom_col` will do it for you.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(DF, aes(x = person, y = n, fill = tokens))+
  geom_col(position = position_stack(reverse = TRUE))+
  geom_text(aes(label = tokens), 
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5, reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

---

Regarding your emoji problem, I do not have any issues. Maybe you should check your version of R and `ggplot2` mine are:

```r
R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Linux Mint 19.2

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.7.1
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.1

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.3       digest_0.6.23    withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.1 crayon_1.3.4    
 [6] dplyr_0.8.4      grid_3.6.3       R6_2.4.1         lifecycle_0.1.0  gtable_0.3.0    
[11] magrittr_1.5     scales_1.1.0     pillar_1.4.3     rlang_0.4.4      farver_2.0.3    
[16] lazyeval_0.2.2   rstudioapi_0.11  labeling_0.3     tools_3.6.3      glue_1.3.1      
[21] purrr_0.3.3      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.6.3   pkgconfig_2.0.3  colorspace_1.4-1
[26] tidyselect_1.0.0 tibble_2.1.3
```

Comment: You beat me to it. I'd mention that we cannot reproduce the problem with the emoji.

Comment: Hahaha, it was close. It took me a while to figure it that it could be much simpler code.

Comment: hi @dc37 thanks fo this! Unfortunately my ggplot do not display emojis despite both ggplot2 (3.3.0) and R (3.6.3) versions are up to date..

Comment: Check the version of all of your package. Maybe there are not all up to date